# How to configure request timeout and/or message TTL separately in MassTransit?

Tags: masstransit

My goal is to make request-response from API Gateway to microservice. I want request to be durable (not expiring), but response should be expiring (if no consumer will receive response within let's say 30s then it should expire). I am using RequestClient in API GW request handler (request scope). By default timeout is set by MassTransit to 30s and after this time request is removed from the queue. It's here in MassTransit code: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/5e2a416384f005c392ead139f5c4af34511c56db/src/MassTransit/RequestTimeout.cs#L7.

First of I tried to set timeout in my request client like that
(using RabbitMQ):

```cs
// on request client level
cfg.AddRequestClient<ICreateGroupPayload>(RequestTimeout.None);

// and/or

// on .GetResponse() level
var response = await _createGroupClient.GetResponse<ICreateGroupResult>(new
            {
                Name = payload.Name,
                Description = payload.Description
            }, new CancellationToken(), RequestTimeout.None);
```

But neither of those options work. Still message has default 30s TTL.

1. Why it does not work as expected? Is message TTL something different here than RequestTimeout? If yes then why its 30s?
2. Do I have to configure message TTL manually in my case?
3. I want request client to automatically timeout after 30s even when request message will never expire. Is this built in, or I have to write some custom code for timeout, or maybe it's enough if I will pass expiring CancellationToken to .getResponse()?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure a default timeout when registering the request client:

```csharp
cfg.AddRequestClient<ICreateGroupPayload>(RequestTimeout.After(s:20));
```

And then, when sending the request, you can override the *TimeToLive* using a header in the message initializer:

```csharp
var response = await _createGroupClient.GetResponse<ICreateGroupResult>(new
{
    Name = payload.Name,
    Description = payload.Description,
    __TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromYears(1)
}, httpContext.CancellationToken);
```

That will replace the default value (which matches the request timeout, by default) with the new value.

Comment: Hmm, it seems it does not work. Tried as you said and also tried in PublishFilter like this: context.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(2); . But no matter what the message always has 30s TTL. Also tried to set milliseconds for __TimeToLive (instead of TimeSpan) but it did not work either. Also when I log message in PublishObserver it shows 00:00:30 TTL.  I am using MT 7.2.0-develop.3353.

Comment: It seems that `__TimeToLive` works only in `RespondAsync` (in consumer it changes response TTL). In `GetResponse` (in request client) `__TimeToLive` is ignored but TTL can be changed by passing third param to `GetResponse(values, cancelationToken, requestTimeout)`. Is it possible to not set any TTL on message? I mean I would like to avoid setting TimeSpan.FromYears(100) for example :). For now I have not figured out how to "not set" TTL at all.