# Request/Response pattern: Stop consumer to reprocess message on application restart

Tags: masstransit

I’m using Masstransit request/response pattern. So I’ve a requester application and a consumer application, which is working very well. I didn’t configure any retry/redelivery as if there is any error happen into consumer , the requester will handle it or might be send another request. So far so good.

But if the consumer application crash and restart in the middle of the process , the consumer try to take the message from queue and start reprocessing it, which is not intended for my case. Because the requester will get error response (or timeout) when the consumer application crashed. I know that MessageRetry in MassTransit is entirely in-memory.

My question is, can we somehow stop consumer to reprocess message on application restart ? OR we need to  remove the pending message from service bus queues?

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between a message sent by the request client and the request client. Using the request timeout as the default value, MassTransit sets the `TimeToLive` of the message to that same value. The transport should remove that message once the TimeToLive has expired.

If the consumer application crashes consuming a message, that message will remain on the queue. If that message repeatedly causes your application to crash, you could check the `Redelivered` property that is on the `ReceiveContext` (a property on `ConsumeContext`) and possibly handle that message another way if you believe the message is causing the process to crash.

> Of course, the real solution is to fix the consumer so it doesn't crash the process...

### UPDATE

You could configure the receive endpoint with a `DeliveryCount` of `1` if you want Azure Service Bus to move the message to the dead-letter queue if the consuming process crashes.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you for your reply.
As I understood from your reply, if I set the TimeToLive property as described here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67201228/how-to-configure-request-timeout-and-or-message-ttl-separately-in-masstransit) then the message will be removed after TimeToLive . 
That means, The message will never be reappear even after restarting the consumer application. Is it correct understanding? Please confirm.

Comment: The message only disappears once the TimeToLive has expired.

Comment: Hi @chris, I would like to inform few things in relation with TimeToLive and DeliveryCount in request/response pattern:  
If I configure the bus control like below, the queue still have the "Default Message Time To Live" is 366 days and message TimeToLive is 30 seconds. Message TimeToLive can only be changed if I configure it during CreateRequestClient but still the message does not move to DLQ. Please note: DeliveryCount is by default 1 on the message.  
 **_busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(conf =>
 {
     conf.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9);
 })**

Comment: That configuration of DefaultMessageTimeToLive only applies to the bus endpoint, not your receive endpoint.

Comment: Hi @chris, Ok, then what actually bus endpoint in Masstransit? I know how to configure ReceiveEndpoint and configure it in consumer.  And I have also configured the Requester Like below :
 **var servicebusConnectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYAPiBus"].ConnectionString;
                _busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(conf =>
                {
                    conf.Host(servicebusConnectionstring);
                    conf.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9);
                });
                await _busControl.StartAsync()**